# Pasar código de C# a Visual Basic .Net

Tags: c#, vb.net

Alguien me puede ayudar el siguiente código de C# a Visual Basic:

```
PageSettings pg = new PageSettings();
pg.Margins.Left = 50;
pg.Margins.Right = 40;
pg.Margins.Top = 50;
pg.Margins.Bottom = 40;
this.reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pg);
```

El código es para modificar los margenes de un ReportViewer. De antemano Gracias.

Comment: Hey broth hay un sitio muy bueno para eso, https://converter.telerik.com/ hay esta la dirección para que resuelvas tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Solo seria convertir la forma en que instancias el objeto

```
Dim pg As PageSettings = New PageSettings()
pg.Margins.Left = 50
pg.Margins.Right = 40
pg.Margins.Top = 50
pg.Margins.Bottom = 40
Me.reportViewer1.SetPageSettings(pg)
```

La primer linea donde se instancia el objeto tambien podria ser

```
Dim pg As New PageSettings
```

Hay tool online que pueden ayudar

http://converter.telerik.com/

Nota: para usar la tool deberas poner el codigo dentro de un metodo